# Observe battery out of charge, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, battery

I want to execute some code when iPhone battery iPhone run out of battery.

Will `func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {` be called? If no then does exist any other way to track this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean some time before it runs out of battery, right? There is a power-save notification when it reaches 20%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for this instead you have to decide when the battery level is so low that you need to run your code.

What you can do is listen to the notification `batteryLevelDidChangeNotification` which is done by activating monitoring see [isBatteryMonitoringEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620045-isbatterymonitoringenabled)

Like mentioned in the documentation the notifications are sent no more than once per minute so you have to determine a battery level that is low enough to be considered as almost depleted and then execute the code.

I have no idea what this could be, from personal experience I have seen my phones stay alive a long time on values under 5% but also seen them die shortly after going below 10%

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code snippet:

```
    func startObservingBatteryDrainage(){
        if UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled && (UIDevice.current.batteryState == .unplugged || UIDevice.current.batteryState == .unknown){
            if UIDevice.current.batteryLevel < 0.1{
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(funcWhenBatteryIsAlmostDrained), name: UIDevice.batteryLevelDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func funcWhenBatteryIsAlmostDrained(){
        //do stuff

    }
```